# Jenkins: Using environment variables or secrets in Branch Sources section of a Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I would like to use a global variable in Jenkins when deciding which branch to build.
Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Not answering your question, but as there is only one sprint at a time, why not use a constant branch name? This is also more user-friendly because there is nothing big to configure and maintain. (feel free to fix your setup by using a constant branch name for CI/CD, but please keep the question open as it is interesting).